# Achieving night effect for 2d game using cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i would like to know if you have any idea how to achieve a night effect without reworking all my images.
Something exactly like in Tiny Wings for iPhone.
Tinting the image in cocos2d doesn't do the trick. I guess there might be some combination with opengl blending that might do it, but i haven't had success.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up placing a blue layer on top and using a multiply effect on it. 
the blend func is: {GL_DST_COLOR, GL_SRC_COLOR}
Here is a blog entry I wrote explaining the process: [PlaySnack Blog - Achieving a night effect in Cocos2d.](http://playsnackgames.com/blog/2011/09/game-programming-adding-a-night-effect-to-you-game-in-cocos2d/)

Comment: could you please fix the link?